# Linking ANSYS workbench with excel

Tags: finite-element-method, ansys

I was trying to use the new interface of ANSYS Workbench to couple ANSYS with Excel without learning Python. I'm having problems because I can only set one parameter in Excel, like one cell. Once I managed to put an array, but I can't do this right now.

What I want to do is this:

My problem has: input x, input y, output z, output w. What I am doing is using the interface in ANSYS, exporting the data, copying to another Excel spreadsheet and after that passing to Origin for better graphs.

What I want to do is have four columns in Excel, put something like 20 values in input x, input y, then update the Workbench project with all design points, and my other two columns in Excel get filled automatically.

Since I can't put an array as a parameter in ANSYS, I am missing the automation of what I want.

Comment: Hi Gabriel Barros, welcome to Engineering SE. For programming sorts of questions it's always better if you can provide a specific example of some input data, some code (or pseudocode), and some result you expect. Rather than describing what you want in general terms, which ends up being vague and more easily misinterpreted, try providing something like Stack Overflow's [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Key component of this might be: How are you setting the one parameter now?